Systemd service not launching as expected
My systemd services aren't launching as expected, despite having symlinks in /etc/systemd/system/*.target.wants. For some reason, I have to put symlinks in /usr/lib/systemd/system/*.target.wants for it to launch
This is a problem because I need to install a debian package (fake-hwclock) that includes systemd services and timers. When I install with dpkg, it automatically creates symlinks in /etc/systemd/system/, but not /usr/lib.
How can I troubleshoot this issue? I'd like to either force systemd to look for the symlinks in /etc/ where dpkg creates them, or force dpkg (or apt) to create symlinks in /usr/lib/. Are either of these things possible?
Here's one of the systemd services (installed in /usr/lib/systemd/system):
[Unit]
Description=Restore the current clock
Documentation=man:fake-hwclock(8)
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=systemd-fsck-root.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/fake-hwclock load

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target

And here is the rules file in the debian package:
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh $@

override_dh_installinit:
    dh_installinit --no-start -- start 02 S . stop 02 0 1 6 .

override_dh_installsystemd:
    dh_installsystemd --name=fake-hwclock-load
    dh_installsystemd --name=fake-hwclock-save



Since this sounds like an embedded platform: Is your /etc actually present on startup? Systemd will not re-scan dependencies if /etc is mounted at a later time during boot.



For this specific example, wouldn't systemd's existing built-in mechanism of restoring hwclock do the job? It already sets the clock from /var/lib/systemd/clock before starting any services.


@u1686_grawity you were right to ask about /etc being present on startup. I found that it actually isn't, and is mounted later. This is the cause of my problem.

I was surprised to see anything in /usr/.../*.wants.d/.  systemctl enable will usually create links in /etc/, but systemctl enable --runtime could make that link in /run/... I suspect anything in /usr/ is probably installed by dh_link instead of using dh_installsystemd.

I looked into plymouth which enables a symlink in /usr/.  The link appears in plymouth.list, so it's definately deployed by the package, and not generated in postinst like normal.  Same deal with dbus.service and package dbus.  The only other links on my machine are owned by package systemd directly.
